# Best way to incorporate legacy data

Tags: c#, sql, batch-file

I am working on a price list management program for my business in C# (Prototype is in Win Forms but am thinking of using WPF for the final ap as a MVVM learning exercise).

Our EMS system is based on a COBOL back end and will remain that way for at least 3 years so I cannot really access it's data directly. I want to pull data from them EMS system periodically to ensure that pricing remains in sync (And to provide some other information to users in a non-editable manner such as bin locations). What I am looking at doing is...

Use WinBatch to automatically run a report nightly then to Use Monarch to convert the text report to a flat file (.xls?)
Drop the file into a folder and write a small ap to read it in and add it to the database

How should I add this to the database? (SQL Express) I could have a table that is just replaced completely each time but I am a beginner at most of this and I am concerned what would happen if an entire table was replaced while the database was being used by the price list ap.

Mike

Comment: I have three answers and am leaning toward codymanix's, thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truncate and refill a whole table you should do it in one single transaction and place a full table lock. This is more secure and faster.

You also could update all changed rows, then insert new (missing rows) and then delete all rows which weren't updated in this run (insert some kind of version number in each row to determine this).

Answer (score 0):

First create a .txt file from the legacy application. Then use a batch insert to pull it into a work table for whatever clean up you need to make. Do the clean up using t-sql. Then run t-sql to insert new data into the proper tables and/or to update rows where data has changed. If there are toomany records, do the inserting and updating in batches. Schedule all this as a job to run during hours when the database is not busy.

You can of course do all of this best in SSIS but I don't know if that is available with Express.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any fields/tables available to tell you when the price was last updated? If so you can just pull the recently updated rows and update that in your database.... assuming you have a readily available unique primary key in your cobol app's datastore.

This wouldn't be up to date though because you're running it as a nightly script to update the database used by the new app. You can maybe create a .net script to query the cobol datastore specifically for whatever price the user is looking for, and if the cobol datastores update time is more recent than what you have logged, update the SQL Server record(s).

(I'm not familiar with cobol at all, just throwing ideas out there)